# Send json data from client to Marklogic Server machine

Tags: javascript, json, curl, nosql, marklogic

Good day to all.

I'm new to Marklogic and was able to create a rest api locally on the machine.
Based on the example, it uses curl to send/create document in the database.

My question is, how can i use/utilize the rest api accessing it from another machine or client via javascript (e.g. send data via ajax)? What is the best practice for client-server tier?

A sample code would be sufficient and appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth reading up on the [Node.js Application Dev guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev).

The [MarkLogic Node.js Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/index.html) might also interest you.

HTH!

Comment: Hi grtjn. Thank you for your response.
I'll take a look on Node.js although still it is a server-side scripting.
I want to achieve is to call marklogic rest-api from a client-side angle like sending/passing data from ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first experience with the Node.js Client API and MarkLogic: http://www.tamas.io/2015/02/08/marklogic-and-node-js/ I hope you'll find this helpful as well.

Comment: Hi Tamas. Thank you for your response.
I'll take a look on Node.js although still it is a server-side scripting.
I want to achieve is to call marklogic rest-api from a client-side angle like sending/passing data from ajax function/call.

Comment: I see. In that case you'll need to also bear in mind CORS requests. You can access any endpoint in MarkLogic from a frontend application but you need to do it via a proxy.